# Segmentation Fault (code dumped)

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I create two files described below

csvreport.h

```
int flag = 0; //declared && defined
```

table.cpp

```
csvreport* csvreports;
csvreports->flag = 1;
```

it is showing segmentation fault (code dumped) 

any one can give solution for it??

Comment: Please provide a mcve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`csvreport* csvreports;` creates uninitialized pointer. Attempt to use uninitialized pointer results in undefined behavior.

Either create this variable on stack, without pointer:

```
csvreport csvreports;
```

or, in case if pointer needed - allocate it first:

```
csvreport* csvreports = new csvreport;
csvreports->flag = 1;
```

or use unique pointer via modern C++11 way:

```
auto csvreports = std::make_unique<csvreport>();
csvreports->flag = 1;
```

Comment: undefined reference to `CSVReports::CSVReports()'

Comment: @GirdhariLal, my examples are assuming, that you have default constructor. If this is not a case - provide necessary arguments to constructor, or define default one.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the member of an object using a pointer that has been declared but not initialized to point to anything valid. That is cause for undefined behavior.

Allocate memory for the object first before attempting to access members of the type.

```
csvreport* csvreports = new csvreport; // or new csvreport[array_size]
csvreports->flag = 1;
```

Comment: undefined reference to `CSVReports::CSVReports()'

Comment: @GirdhariLal, that is an entirely different problem. Create another post for that, with a [mcve].

Comment: I used your solution then it is showing this error: undefined reference to `CSVReports::CSVReports()' @R Sahu

Comment: @GirdhariLal, I understand. I repeat. That is an entirely different problem. Create another post for that, with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
csvreport* csvreports;
csvreports->flag = 1;
```

`cvsreports` is just declared as a pointer; no memory is allocated for it to point to.